# Show records in horizontal in Qlikview only one column

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I'm loading the info from Oracle:

The problem is that I have a table that contains years but when I create the listbox, it shows the info in this way:

```
Year
----
2011
2012
2013
```

I need that information like this:

```
Year
----
2011 | 2012  | 2013 | 2014
```

I think that is only a configuration of the listbox or I have to use another element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In QlikView:**

- right click on the listbox and select `Properties`
- navigate to the `Presentation` tab
- Uncheck `Single Column`
- Close the properties form
- start resizing your listbox until is one row (consider the object width)

Optional:

- `Fixed Number of Columns` can be specified as well

[image]

Result

[image]

**In Qlik Sense:**

I dont think this is possible by default. But there are number of extensions that are addressing this on [Qlik Branch](http://branch.qlik.com)

One example being [q2g-ext-listbox](http://branch.qlik.com/#!/project/5a8bc4b21fa39860374dfd24)